# Using EXIT command in an SSH bash script loop

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I have created a script to SSH into 3 x remote virtual machines and SCP some information back to the local machine. Is there a way to insert the EXIT command into my script to automatically exit the shell of the existing IP address in the loop before before moving onto the next iteration please? At the moment the script works but I am automatically having to CTRL + D in the command line to get the script to SSH into the next IP Address in the loop. Here is a sample of my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

addresses='IP address 1 IP Address 2 IP Address2' #Array to store remote IP addresses
scp=$(scp -r root@$i:/root/Outputs /root)#SCP to bring files back to local computer

cpu=1 #Increment variable for the resulting .txt file for each computer

mkdir Outputs

for i in $addresses
do

ping -c 1 $i>/dev/null #Test ping to see if machine is ON

if [ $? -eq 0 ]  # IF statement: if ping response not equal to 0 then get info 
then
user="root"
ssh $user@$i   #SSH onto remote machines in loop

# GET CPU INFORMATION #

else 
 echo "Node0$cpu off" >> Outputs/Node$a.txt

fi
let "cpu=cpu+1" #Incrementing variable by one for next iteration of loop
done

$scp #Run secure copy command stored within scp variable
```

Many thanks

Comment: You should probably design it such that you run a specific command (like `ssh $user@i 'command arg1 arg2'`) on the remote machine - that way it won't enter an interactive shell session at all and there's no need to exit from anything

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome - see this related question for an example [How to echo or paste commands into a SSH terminal with a shell script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217703/how-to-echo-or-paste-commands-into-a-ssh-terminal-with-a-shell-script)