# How to echo or paste commands into a SSH terminal with a shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh

I've been having an issue lately trying to figure out how to get my shell script to paste a command into a ssh terminal after automatically logging into an ssh terminal. I am trying to setup a cron tab that will execute my shell script that automatically logs into an ssh terminal for my Ubiquiti access point and inserts a command to turn the LED off at a certain time. So far I've been able to automatically SSH into the access point when I run the shell script but when it logs in it doesn't paste the command. After I manually exit the SSH terminal, the echo command runs and put the command in after leaving the terminal. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure this out. I've been looking everywhere but can't find any answers. Thank you ahead of time. This is the code I have currently in my shell script. The command I want to be able to run in the SSH terminal is ("mgmt.led_pattern_override=2" >> /var/etc/persistent/cfg/mgmt)

```
   #!/bin/sh
sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@192.168.1.3;
   echo '"mgmt.led_pattern_override=2" >> /var/etc/persistent/cfg/mgmt';
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting an interactive ssh session, pass the echo command directly as an argument to ssh:

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@192.168.1.3 '
   echo "mgmt.led_pattern_override=2" >> /var/etc/persistent/cfg/mgmt
'
```

Your other option would be to use `expect` to script the interactive session - but that's overcomplicated for this case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ended up taking your format and found the exec command followed by double quotes when I was messing  with it and it and it turned out to work, thank you very much! In place of the echo line I used                                                             [exec ""echo "mgmt.led_pattern_override=2" >> /var/etc/persistent/cfg/mgmt""]